# HTTPS requirements - express server on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have written an express application which I have deployed on AWS. I want to understand if I need to enable https in my node js express server code or if the https enabled in the AWS console is enough i.e. is https between the web client and the AWS load balancer enough to protect my site or do i need to enable https within AWS infrastructure internally as well. Are there any other security considerations to be aware of in this scenario?